# What's the purpose of a 2GB+ VMDK file provided in a virtual machine image download?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I wanted to learn Puppet using [this book by PacktPub](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/learning-puppet) and so I downloaded the Puppet Learning VM v.3.7.1 package that's provided for the book.

The VM package comes with the files shown below:

[image: VM package]

The instructions in the book state to import the OVF file to VirtualBox but they do not say anything about what to do with the 2GB+ "learn_puppet_centos-6.5-disk1.vmdk" file.

When I configure the import, if I select the default settings for all parameters except that I point the Storage Controller (IDE) > Virtual Disk Image parameter to this VMDK image, I get this error:

> Failed to import appliance ...\learn_puppet_centos-6.5.ovf.
>
> Could not create the imported medium
>   '...\learn_puppet_centos-6.5-disk1.vmdk'.
>
> VMDK: could not create new file
>   '.../learn_puppet_centos-6.5-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
>
> Component: ApplianceWrap
>
> Interface: IAppliance {8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e}

It looks like the import process wants to create its own new VMDK file instead of allowing me to use the one that was downloaded.

Considering that I can not specify the VMDK file as a parameter during the import process, is it somehow automatically recognized and used by the import process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VMDK file is the Virtual Machine Disk. Basically it's the disk that will be attached to the Virtual Machine once you import it. You don't need to specify it explicitly, as it is referenced in the `OVF` file you're trying to import.

As for the error, it seems that it has nothing to do with the appliance itself but it's rather a inconsistency state of VirtualBox. You might find more info in these links:

- [Error importing appliance50-17](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=58315)
- [Cant create Virtual Mashines with the new VirtualBox](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms/issues/192)
- [Cannot import ova file (Virtualbox)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172915)